# No new project type in expression blend

Tags: wpf, silverlight, windows-phone-7, expression-blend, expression-blend-4

I am new in expression blend. When I try to create a project in expression blend, it only listing windows phone project. But I want to create WPF project. How can I install other project types in expression blend. I want WPF and Silverlight project types too...

Now my create new project menu in expression blend is  like below

[image]

but I want like below

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is because you only have Blend for Windows Phone installed (a free version).

- [Blend comes with Visual Studio 2012 Pro](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/).
- [Expression Blend 4](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5915) supports WPF etc and Silverlight up to version 4.
- [Expression Blend for Silverlight](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=9503) is also available but only supports Silverlight 5 projects

Be warned, it may be difficult to revert to the Windows Phone edition if you decide to install a trial version of Blend 4. Once the trial expires you may be stuck with it.